# Precedence of heredocs and compound commands in bash

Tags: bash, operator-precedence, heredoc

I want my shell script to print out a simple usage instruction and then exit when it is called without arguments. Here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
(($#)) || cat <<EOF && exit

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Usage: Donec a diam lectus.

EOF

echo "You have provided at least one argument"
```

(The special bash variable `$#` holds the number of arguments, and surrounding it with double parentheses makes it evaluate to false when there are no arguments).

This works when there are no arguments, but exits immediately without printing anything if there *are* arguments. I thinks it's due to the wrong precedence of the operators. How can I fix this script to do what I want?

Comment: The here-doc doesn't affect the precedence. You'd have the same problem if you had `echo foo` instead of `cat <<EOF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use curly braces to group the commands:

```
(($#)) || { cat <<EOF && exit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Usage: Donec a diam lectus.

EOF
}
echo "You have provided at least one argument"
```

Or you could just give up on the compact format, and use `if`:

```
if [[ $# == 0 ]]
then cat <<EOF && exit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Usage: Donec a diam lectus.

EOF
fi

echo "You have provided at least one argument"
```

Comment: good answer. I would use an `else` branch instead of `exit`ing

Comment: If it's just a few lines, that's fine. But I don't like having a long script almost entire in an `else` block.

Comment: True, but that seems unnecessarily cryptic. What's wrong with saying what you mean? If you want to compare a number with `0`, write `== 0`.

Comment: Although, `[[ $# -eq 0 ]]` would be the correct numeric comparison. Or `(( $# == 0 ))`

Comment: Yeah, although the distinction between numeric and string comparison is not too important in cases like this. It's important not to use numeric comparison when you can have string values, but using string comparison on numbers is generally safe.